# Two tableView functions conflicts with each other

Tags: uitableview, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {              
            return self.arrayLength
        }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return cell
}
```

And it prints the next error: "Previous definition of 'tableView' is here"(Definition conflicts with previous value). Why they conflicts with each other?

Comment: lets stop trying to fix your problem here, please come to the chat and we'll see how we can fix it here's the link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62028/swift-objective-c-ios

Answer (score 3):

So we finally found the answer for this. First at all [the whole code for the Problem](http://pastebin.com/W0zcn6gW). (The JSON things coming from [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON))

The problem here was that Orkhan forgot to use the UITableViewDataSource protocol in the class definition and did not set the tableView.dataSource na delegate to his own class. After doing so the problem is solved.